# Regex to ignore only price within a string

Tags: java, regex

For eg:
*Input* =>  **"Some.Random ,,Test.Data Here with price 1,23.456...,$$$"**
*Output Match* => Everything except **1,23.456**

*Price*  is defined as any string beginning & ending with a digit, having one or more character separators.
eg:

  1.23,456

  123456

  1:23;456

  1.23.456

*Please Note* , all that is known about the input , is that it can be any length string , but with a Price embedded somewhere  within.

Basically the problem being solved is to extract the Price from an input string using the String ReplaceAll which is a built'in runtime function in the system. So i would say
 ReplaceAll(Regex,EMPTY_String) which would return only the price from the input

I have been trying something on the lines of "**[\D&&[^(?<=\d)\D(?=\d)]]**" wherein I would match all Non-Digits and any Non-Digit which does NOT occur b/w  a Digit ,only using Regex.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there whitespace between price and 1,23.456 and is that the last space in the string? If it is you could just cut the string there.

Comment: Also, is there really a comma between the number and the currency symbol (and are there always 3 currency symbols)?

Comment: @pavan: How is _price_ defined? Is any number in the string a price? Only ones followed by a dollar sign? Is there a comma between the number and the dollar signs, like in your example? Please edit the question and add some details, or the question is too vague to be answered and I'lll vote to close it.

Comment: `replaceAll` isn't meant to be use for extraction; instead, use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` with either answer's regex in order to extract a substring.

Comment: The replaceAll is a function which i need to use to accomplish extracting the price from a string. It internally uses Pattern & matcher to do the replace.

Answer (score 2):

This [regex (demo)](http://fiddle.re/bxm9) should do the trick:

```
^(.*?)(?:\d[0-9.,]*\d)(.*)$
```

as Java string:

```
"^(.*?)(?:\\d[0-9.,]*\\d)(.*)$"
```

to be replaced with 1st and 2nd captured groups:

```
$1$2
```

as in:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("^(.*?)(?:\\d[0-9.,]*\\d)(.*)$", "$1$2");
```

Comment: It's noteworthy that he has to extract group 1 and 2 to get his desired output.